# Lose user tasks after closing visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

If I add some user tasks in Task List of Visual Studio (2013), and then close and reopen Visual Studio, all user tasks are lost. Is this a bug? Or Visual Studio does not support saving user tasks? Please give me an idea.

Comment: FWIW, I see the same thing, and I cannot find a way to save user tasks. That doesn't mean there isn't a way, but if there is then it is well hidden. Perhaps it is tied to using source control.

Comment: Works fine on my machine™.  Keep in mind where they are stored, embedded in the hidden .v12.suo file in the solution directory.  Use connect.microsoft.com when you can demonstrate a repro for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is just a bug or Microsoft decided that it won't work if you don't add your project to source control.

Try this.. make a new project and check the option "add to source control" then select git, that will create a local git repository for your project.

to that new project add some to tasks to test and close it visual studio.

You will see that your tasks were saved and you can see them again when reopen the project.

let me know if that works ;)

Comment: and if you add your current project to source control GIT it will be work the task list ;)
why minus one? :( who voted like that my answer :(